# react-native-webrtc remote stream not working

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, webrtc

I am trying to create a video calling app using react-native-webrtc. I am tring to store the local stream in Firebase Firestore and then get that stream from there to show it. But when I get the stream from the database I have no idea what should be done with it to make it work.

Here is what I get from my database:

```
id: "494fd1cb-ebf0-43d4-89d2-126961e0c50e"
active: true
_reactTag: "a9caac52-3095-4b10-b519-ca2e1238e9dc"
_tracks: Array(1)
0: {muted: false, _enabled: true, remote: true, label: "Video", id: "182e3c8e-b141-493b-bbd9-81b0582a221d", …}
```

After retrieving this I don't know what I should do with it.

Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: I am working on the same type of app (firebase webrtc react native audio and video call) can you please help me in doing that or can you please share a code with me

Answer (score 0):

You can store this object in the state object and then show the stream by rendering

```
<RTCView streamURL={this.state.stream.toURL()}/>
```